# In python using pydantic models, how to access nested dict with unknown keys?

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic

I have data with a nested dict containing IDs as keys and data objects as values. I am trying to convert this into a pydantic model.

Sometimes there is a need to access a nested value if it exists. However, making an if check every time when accessing a nested object is very verbose. E.g.:

```
from typing import Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel

class EventModel(BaseModel):
    eventId: str
    eventName: str

class UserModel(BaseModel):
    userId: str
    events: Dict[str, EventModel]

user_dict = {
    'userId': 'abc',
    'events': {
        'xyz': {'eventId': 'xyz', 'eventName': 'User log in'},
        '123': {'eventId': '123', 'eventName': 'User log out'},
    },
}
user = UserModel(**user_dict)
unknown_id = '987'

# Inconvenient access pattern if there are multiple nested ID maps on the way
if user.events.get(unknown_id):
    print(user.events[unknown_id].eventName)

# Compare to the more convenient dict access pattern
print(user_dict['events'].get(unknown_id, {}).get('eventName'))
```

If the object is deep, the access pattern with if statements become very ugly.

Is there a more convenient way to access nested values with ID mappings on the way using pydantic? Or is there a way to improve this pydantic model to be more scalable without changing the underlying data structure?

Answer (score 3):

For a simple translation of your "more convenient dict access pattern", you could try this, which uses the optional default parameter of the [built-in getattr function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
getattr(user.events.get(unknown_id), 'eventName', None)
```

A more efficient solution, however, might be to add a method to `UserModel` that will return as soon as it is known that there is no event with that ID. The following suggested solution follows the ["Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python) pattern.

```
from typing import Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel

class EventModel(BaseModel):
    eventId: str
    eventName: str

class UserModel(BaseModel):
    userId: str
    events: Dict[str, EventModel]

    def name_of_event_with_id(event_id, default=None):
        try:
            event = self.events[event_id]
        except KeyError:
            return default
        else:
            return event.eventName
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up augmenting the library itself to include many features from the python dict interface, which helps quite a bit.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel as PydanticBasemodel


class BaseModel(PydanticBasemodel):
    # Enable instance[field] syntax
    def __getitem__(self, field):
        return getattr(self, field)

    def __setitem__(self, field, new_value):
        return setattr(self, field, new_value)

    # Enable spreading like a dict: func(**model)
    def keys(self):
        return self.__fields__.keys()

    # Enable dict like get
    def get(self, field, default=None):
        return self[field] if field in self.keys() else default

    # Change default config
    class Config:
        validate_assignment = True
```